# Is it possible to remove files from Spark Streaming folder?

Tags: spark-streaming, parquet

Spark 2.1, ETL process convert files from source systems into parquet and put small parquets in folder1. Spark streaming on folder1 is working OK, but parquet files in folder1 too small for HDFS. We have to merge small parquet files in bigger one, but when I try to remove files from folder1, spark streaming process rise exception:

17/07/26 17:16:23 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = f29783ea-bdfb-4b59-a6f6-b77f79509a5a, runId = cbcce2b2-7d7b-4e31-a15a-7efed420f974] terminated with error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist

Is it possible to merge parquet files in spark streaming folder ?

```
    Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val userSchema = new StructType()
  .add("itemId", "string")
  .add("tstamp", "integer")
  .add("rowtype", "string")
  .add("rowordernumber", "integer")
  .add("parentrowordernumber", "integer")
  .add("fieldname", "string")
  .add("valuestr", "string")

val csvDF = spark.readStream.schema(userSchema).parquet("/folder1/folder2")

csvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tab1")
val aggDF = spark.sql("select distinct count(itemId) as cases_count from tab1")
aggDF
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()

aggDF
.writeStream
.queryName("aggregates")    // this query name will be the table name
.outputMode("complete")
  .format("memory")
  .start()
spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
+-----------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
userSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(itemId,StringType,true), StructField(tstamp,IntegerType,true), StructField(rowtype,StringType,true), StructField(rowordernumber,IntegerType,true), StructField(parentrowordernumber,IntegerType,true), StructField(fieldname,StringType,true), StructField(valuestr,StringType,true))
csvDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [itemId: string, tstamp: int ... 5 more fields]
aggDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cases_count: bigint]

scala> -------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
|  292086106|
+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
|  292086106|
+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
|  292086106|
+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
|  292086106|
+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 4
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
|  324016758|
|  292086106|
+-----------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 5
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+
|cases_count|
+-----------+
|  355839229|
|  324016758|
|  292086106|
+-----------+

17/07/26 17:16:23 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = f29783ea-bdfb-4b59-a6f6-b77f79509a5a, runId = cbcce2b2-7d7b-4e31-a15a-7efed420f974] terminated with error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /folder1/folder2/P-FMVDBAF-4021-20161107152556-1_006.gz.parquet
```

Comment: Is this Spark Streaming or Structured Streaming? Care to share some code? Looks like Structured Streaming. Can you also include the entire stacktrace?

Comment: I've updated main post with sample code, yes it is structured streaming and I use spark-shell to execute the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use globbing to only process files you need. Like this:

```scala
val csvDF = spark.readStream.schema(userSchema).parquet("/folder1/folder2/bigger_file*.parquet")
```